# Obtain specific part of a string with JSON Format java

Tags: java, json, string, format

I have a question on how would be the best way to get the information from a string but that has JSON format.

```
{
"internal_id":"1234",
"moreInformation":"Failed authentication for user."
}
```

In this case, I want to get the value of "internal_id" and I already did, with subtring, lastIndexOf and indexOf

```
public static String returnInternalCode(String json){
    String internalCode = json.substring(json.lastIndexOf("\"internal_id\":\"") + "\"internal_id\":\"".length(), json.length() - 1);
    if (json.lastIndexOf("\"internal_id\":\"") == -1) return null;
    return internalCode.substring(0, internalCode.indexOf("\""));
}
```

I also tried several JSONs with order changes that don't have the data and it also worked. I leave the full class of tests I did:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Original JSON
        String json = "{\"internal_id\":\"999999\",\"moreInformation\":\"Failed authentication for user, 1 authentication attempt remaining.\"}";

        // Other JSON order
        String json2 = "{\"moreInformation\":\"Failed authentication for user. Invalid response.\", \"moreInformation2\":\"Failed authentication for user. \", \"internal_id\":\"45678\"}";

        // JSON without the internal_id
        String json3 = "{\"moreInformation\":\"Failed authentication for user. Invalid response.\"}";

        // JSON without moreInformation
        String json4 = "{\"internal_id\":\"999999\"}";

        System.out.println("JSON: ".concat(json4));
        System.out.println("internalId: " + returnInternalId(json4));
        System.out.println("moreInformation: " + returnMoreInformation(json4));
    }

    public static String returnInternalId(String json){
        String internalCode = json.substring(json.lastIndexOf("\"internal_id\":\"") + "\"internal_id\":\"".length(), json.length());
        if (json.lastIndexOf("\"internal_id\":\"") == -1) return null;
        return internalCode.substring(0, internalCode.indexOf("\""));
    }

    public static String returnMoreInformation(String json){
        String moreInformation = (json.substring(json.lastIndexOf("\"moreInformation\":\"") + "\"moreInformation\":\"".length(), json.length()));
        if (json.lastIndexOf("\"moreInformation\":\"") == -1) return null;
        return moreInformation.substring(0, moreInformation.indexOf("\""));
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there are better ways to do what I did, such as with StringBuilder or StringBuffer and also to find out which way uses less memory or is faster to run, how do I know that? How long does it take to execute a method?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Preferred way would be using proper **JSON parser** and then getting value of selected key. This saves us from a lot of bugs you will face when your JSON structure will grow and potentially contain as value key you ware looking for (and that is only one of many possible problems parser solves for us).

Comment: i will suggest to use `gson` library

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the values this way; Using Simple-json library

```
    JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(yourJsonString); // Pass the Json formatted String

    String internal_id = (String) jobj.get("internal_id"); // Extract the value from your key

    System.out.println(internal_id); // 1234
```